# Type in lightning navigation

Tags: lightning, navigation

In the following code what is passed to type key?

```
    var pageRef = {
        type: 'custom__recordPage', // What is type here?
        attributes: {
            actionName: 'view',
            objectApiName: 'Inventory__c',
            recordId : resp
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the value for the page *reference* type. E.g., if you are navigating to a record page type, then your `type` value will be `standard__recordPage`.

> A pageReference must be defined with a specific type. The type generates a unique URL format and provides attributes that apply to all pages of that type.

Below are the supported page types as listed in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) along with their *type* values.

> - Lightning Component (*type: standard__component*)
> - Knowledge Article (*type: standard__knowledgeArticlePage*)
> - Named Page (*type: standard__namedPage*)
> - Navigation Item Page (*type: standard__navItemPage*)
> - Object Page (*type: standard__objectPage*)
> - Record Page (*type: standard__recordPage*)
> - Record Relationship Page (*type: standard__recordRelationshipPage*)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I know my page reference type?

Comment: It depends on to which page reference type you are navigating to. The documentation lists down all *type* values.